# Converting and displaying the fetched data to Bamini format

Tags: php, mysql, css, pdf, utf-8

I have stored the data in the table using the collation `utf8_unicode_520_ci`. And also have fetched it in my page. But the text remains same while I have added the `font-family` as `Bamini`

```
<input type="text" name="ra1" class="ra1" style="height:60px; width:80px; font-family:Bamini;" value="<?php echo $select_fetch['8'];?>" />

<style>
@font-face {

font-family: 'Bamini';

src: url('font/Bamini.ttf');

}

#ra1{
    font-family: Bamini, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

</style>
```

How to convert it to the given `font`??

Comment: does your font *Bamini.ttf* exist in the *font* folder?

Comment: me too have the same problem. bro have u found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the path to font is right and you have this font on your server/system? Actually, it works

```
  <style>
   h1 {
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   } 
   p {
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
   }


  </style>
```

See also this [Overriding @font-face src URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901500/overriding-font-face-src-url)

Comment: Ya it works for other fonts but I need to display the value in TAMIL. And it is not working for BAMINI font.

Comment: Ya everything alright here. But the conversion of the text to the particular font is not working.

Comment: Try to use the validator first to check if your font source is fine https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ And then, try to generate a new font face http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be worked, actually, mine is and I have mapped the baamini.ttf file for the Bamini font. try this.

```
<style>
      body {
        background-image: url("image.jpg");
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: "Bamini";

        src: url("./font/baamini.ttf");
      }

      h1 {
        font-family: Bamini, sans-serif;
      }

      p {
        font-family: Bamini, sans-serif;
      }

      b {
        font-family: Bamini, sans-serif;
      }
 </style>
```

Download link for the font: https://www.tamiltypingonline.com/bamini-tamil-font-free-download/