# Duplicate @font-face declaration in css, url fetched twice?

Tags: css

I'm overriding a `@font-face` css declaration:

```
/* ORIGINAL */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font1';
  src: url('/PATH1/font1.eot');
  ...
}

/* MY OVERRIDE */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font1';
  src: url('/PATH2/font1.eot');
  ...
}
```

and i've noticed that browsers try to take both paths `'/PATH2/font1.eot'` and `'/PATH1/font1.eot'`.
Is there a way to avoid one of two fetch, leaving only one?

Thanks

Comment: you'd have to remove it from the original, else, you litteraly ask the computer to load the font and then you ask him to load another font and tells him that it overrides the first one...

Comment: Maybe this can help U http://stackoverflow.com/a/16904853/2887133

Answer (score 0):

The @font-face rule defines an external font:

```html
<style id="customfont">
@font-face {

  font-family: a_font;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/quicksand/v22/6xK-dSZaM9iE8KbpRA_LJ3z8mH9BOJvgkP8o58a-wg.woff2);
}

body {
  font-family: a_font !important;
}
</style>
<p>Some text. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog... but it didn't make it up all the way.</p>
```

To change it, modify the `innerHTML` property of the element.

Here are the ways to modify the HTML code of an element:

```
+--------------+------------------------------+
| innerHTML    | HTML within the tags         |
+--------------+------------------------------+
| outerHTML    | HTML, with the tags          |
+--------------+------------------------------+
| appendChild  | add an element to the end    |
+--------------+------------------------------+
| prepend      | prepend element              |
+--------------+------------------------------+
```

This example uses innerHTML:

```html
<style id="customfont">
@font-face {

  font-family: a_font;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/quicksand/v22/6xK-dSZaM9iE8KbpRA_LJ3z8mH9BOJvgkP8o58a-wg.woff2);
}

body {
  font-family: a_font !important;
}
</style>
<p>Some text. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog... but it didn't make it up all the way.</p>
<button onclick="change()">Change @font-face src</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change() {
  var newstyle=document.getElementById('customfont');
  var newfontsrc="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sofia/v9/8QIHdirahM3j_su5uI0.woff2";
  var newtext = '@font-face {\n';
  newtext += 'font-family:a_font;\n';
  newtext += 'src:url('+newfontsrc+');\n';
  newtext += '}\n';
  newtext += '\nbody {\n'
  newtext += '  font-family:a_font !important;\n';
  newtext += '}'
  newstyle.innerHTML=newtext;
}
</script>
```

This should change the font src.